# Slony lib not found

Tags: postgresql, slony

Trying to run the example slony config script in the documentation but getting the following error:

```
postgres$ /tmp/slonik_example.sh 
<stdin>:8: PGRES_FATAL_ERROR load '$libdir/slony1_funcs';  - ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/slony1_funcs": No such file or directory 
<stdin>:8: Error: the extension for the Slony-I C functions cannot be loaded in database 'dbname=my_primary host=localhost user=warfish password=coalitions'
```

Yet the LIBDIR variable is set correctly:

```
postgres$ ./pg_config 
BINDIR = /opt/local/lib/postgresql90/bin 
DOCDIR = /opt/local/share/doc/postgresql 
HTMLDIR = /opt/local/share/doc/postgresql 
INCLUDEDIR = /opt/local/include/postgresql90 
PKGINCLUDEDIR = /opt/local/include/postgresql90 
INCLUDEDIR-SERVER = /opt/local/include/postgresql90/server 
LIBDIR = /opt/local/lib/postgresql90
```

And the lib is present:

```
ls -l /opt/local/lib/postgresql90/slony1_funcs.so 
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin  34944 Feb 17 16:20 /opt/local/lib/postgresql90/slony1_funcs.so
```

Script is as follows:

```
cat /tmp/slonik_example.sh 
#!/bin/sh 

CLUSTERNAME=slony_example; 
/opt/local/lib/postgresql90/bin/slonik <<_EOF_ 
define CLUSTERNAME slony_example; 
cluster name = @CLUSTERNAME; 
node 1 admin conninfo = 'dbname=my_primary host=localhost user=user1 password=pw'; 
node 2 admin conninfo = 'dbname=my_rep host=localhost user=user1 password=pw'; 
#-- 
# init the first node. Its id MUST be 1. This creates the schema # _$CLUSTERNAME containing all replication system specific database # objects. 
#-- 
init cluster ( id=1, comment='Master Node'); 
#-- 
# Slony-I organizes tables into sets. The smallest unit a node can # subscribe is a set. The following commands create one set containing # all 4 pgbench tables. The master or origin of the set is node 1. 
#-- 
create set (id=1, origin=1, comment='All pgbench tables'); 
set add table (set id=1, origin=1, id=1, fully qualified name='public.pgbench_accounts', comment='accounts table'); 
set add table (set id=1, origin=1, id=2, fully qualified name='public.pgbench_branches', comment='branches table'); 
set add table (set id=1, origin=1, id=3, fully qualified name='public.pgbench_tellers', comment='tellers table'); 
set add table (set id=1, origin=1, id=4, fully qualified name='public.pgbench_history', comment='history table'); 
#-- 
# Create the second node (the slave) tell the 2 nodes how to connect to Slony-I 2.1.1 Documentation 10 / 163 
# each other and how they should listen for events. 
#-- 
store node (id=2, comment = 'Slave node', event node=1); 
store path (server = 1, client = 2, conninfo='dbname=my_primary host=localhost user=user1 password=pw'); 
store path (server = 2, client = 1, conninfo='dbname=my_rep host=localhost user=user1 password=pw'); 
_EOF_
```

Read in the doc that likely the lib is not in the correct place or $libdir is not set correctly, but everything looks to be in place.  Am I missing something else I am not aware of?

Comment: Did you check file system level permissions and database level permissions on slony trigger functions? Is the slony version you are using OK for PostgreSQL 9.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my situation, this error was caused by Slony not being installed *on every machine in the cluster*. I had Slony installed and all the requisite libs on the main host/master, but the clients needed Slony installed (or maybe just the library functions file put in `$libdir`) as well.

Answer (score 1):

In my database slony1_funcs.so it is in the PKGLIBDIR directory

PKGLIBDIR = /usr/lib64/pgsql

I found this information about "PKGLIBDIR vs LIBDIR":

" *libdir is for build-time linkable libraries, anything that you might want
to pass as -lxxx. So typical locations are /usr/lib, /usr/local/lib, or
/usr/local/pgsql/lib. pkglibdir is for dynamically loadable libraries*"